# SharePoint 2013 Server Search status stuck on "Unprovisioning"

Tags: sharepoint-server, search, enterprise-search

I am having some problems with search. I had stopped it because I had to perform an update. After the update it did not want to start again. So, I tried to start the search service using powershell:

```
Get-SPEnterpriseSearchServiceInstance -Local | Stop-SPEnterpriseSearchServiceInstance
```

Now status is stuck on "Unprovisioning".

```
TypeName    : SharePoint Server Search
Description : Index content and serve search queries
Id          : eb9f4c5d-b9d4-4cdb-a92f-2e4d8d0eda1a
Server      : SPServer Name=ABC02
Service     : SearchService Name=OSearch15
Role        : None
Status      : Unprovisioning
```

I added search service account in the local administrators group. 
I have restarted SharePoint Administration, SP Search, SP Timer, SP Search Host controller services.

Nothing so far.

Anything else I should do now to stop it and fix this issue?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I suggest you re-provisioning the Search Service Application using PowerShell command:

1. Find the service which need to be provisioned.

`Get-SPServiceInstance -All`

2. Then run the commands to provision:

   `$service = Get-SPServiceInstance -Identity [paste in the GUID for the service]`

   `$service.provision()`

   `$service.update()`

   `iisreset /noforce`

Comment: sorry had tried it before, tried it again now. Did not work. Still saying paused for: external request

Comment: I am not sure if you suggestion solved the issue, but it is working at this moment. I restarted Search via UI and it worked. I am accepting your answer anyway.